# Python Base class for instantiating API query module

Tags: python

So I am writing a datamodel in python that interacts with an python module that queries the api.

```
class QueryAPI():
   def __init__(self, clientid, clientsecret):
      self.clientid = clientid
      self.clientsecret = clientsecret
   def create_user_info(self, name, address):
        ......



class MyModel(object):
   def __init__(self, name, address);
      self.name = name
      self.address = address
   def commit():
      create_user_info(name, address)
```

and this api has lot more functions that will be used by my other datamodels. Right now, I am wondering where should I instantiate this QueryAPI object. Does it make sense to have a base class that instantiate it and have all my data models access it from there?

Comment: `Does it make sense to have a base class that instantiate it and have all my data models access it from there?` -- That depends on whether or not you need the features and functionality that a base class provides.

Comment: I need it. Also, I want to have a abstract method called commit ?. Following python idiom is it good to have base class and abstract method inside it.

Comment: Sounds like you already know the answer.

Comment: so you are saying yes

Comment: I am saying that, if you need it, you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the concept of a connection object (similar to how database driver libraries work) . Your API clients will instantiate your QueryAPI object once passing the clientid and secret.

```
client = QueryAPI(clientid, clientsecret)

user = User(name, address)
client.create_user(user)
```

If your data model objects can in turn own child objects it might be better to keep a reference to the QueryAPI in each data model to provide a  more fluent interface.

```
client = QueryAPI(clientid, clientsecret)

user = client.create_user(firstname, lastname) # return a new user object with a reference to the QueryAPI
user.commit()

childentity = user.create_child_entity(attribute1, attribute2) # return a new child entity with reference to user and the QueryAPI 
childentity.commit()
```